# Rpi3 and RPi0W wifi signal strength

Tags: pi-3, wifi, pi-zero-w

I have a rpi3 which act as a Homeassistant hub, and have no problems connecting to my wifi.

Problem is that my rpi0W can't seem to connect to the same wireless network, from the same position that my rpi3 is located.  Actually if I am placed 2 meter away from router AP - i get an signal connection strength of ~-80dB, and when i enter the room with the rpi3, i simple loose connection due to bad signal strength?

is the rpi0W that bad in terms of wifi signal range coverage? and 
can I do anything to improve it?

its in no case, and powered by a computer usb terminal

Comment: what sort of case is the rpi0W in, if any

Comment: Hi fat guy, I have three RpiZW and RpiZ and they are placed about 2 meters away.  I never found any problems connecting WiFi.  After playing RpiZ 10+ hours I found that comparing to Rpi3B+, everything of RpiZ hardware and software is slow and weak.  But I am not complaining, because for a dirt cheap computer, I am more than happy.  BTW, I think you can  try upgrading your Wifi router.

Comment: @JaromandaX its in no case, and powered by a computer usb terminal